# Vline - anyway to prevent connecting panel covering the browser?

Tags: css, vline

I am using vline php for video chatting in my websites, the video call has no problem,

but each time, when user1 call user2, after user2 answer the call, there would be a big gray screen in user1's browser with a center box saids "connecting user2".  The big gray screen would be stayed there with user1's video chat screen, and it really affects the image sharpness for user1. In user2's browser, there is only the video chat screen which has no problem.

So the question is, is there anyway to remove the gray screen for caller?

I used chrome "Inspect element" and have found out the gray panel is a div brought in by vline.css, which looks like this:

```
    <div class="vl-not-dialog-bg" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1; width: 1343px; height: 240px;"></div>
```

I edited "opacity:0" using "Inspect element" and the panel is disappeared successfully, so I tried to change the div style before startmedia by using this code:

```
    if(button.hasClass('active')){
              var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('vl-not-dialog-bg');
              for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
              var item = cusid_ele[i];  
              item.style.opacity = 0;
              }

            person.startMedia();
            }
```

but no luck, the gray panel still exists when caller make calls, check that div's opacity again, still opacity:1, so what can I do, how can I change the css element which from https://static.vline.com/vline.css?

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: I have the same problem. But both in Firefox as well as Chrome.